# If same score then same rank in RAILS 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I have a ranking system wherein if they have same score or points then both users should have same rank.

I am getting it thru the index, but can't manage to make their indexes both equal if they have same score

**user.rb**

```
def get_rank
    x = User.get_rank.index(self)
    x ? (x + 1) : x
end

def self.get_rank
  Response.joins(:answer).where("answers.correct is TRUE").map(&:user).uniq.sort_by(&:score).reject{|me| me.super_admin or me.questions.count < Question.count}.reverse
end
```

How can I make the users who have same scores to have just 1 similar rank.

E.g. if both users get 25 points, and 25 is the highest from the postings, then they must have the first rank.

Any workarounds will be appreciated

Comment: How about you get all the scores and get index of that user score instead? However, this seems rather inefficient though. Say you are displaying rank of 1000 users for example.

Comment: In common sense rank is within a range, say score 0 to 100 is rank 1, 100 to 500 rank 2, blah blah. If rank is same as score, there is no need for rank, using score directly is enough.

Comment: So I should implement a range?

Comment: Yes, definitely, if you want to implement rank feature.

Answer (score 2):

The question is rather confusing but I think you could make better use of the database functions. Maybe something like this works, since I don't know your full models, especially which object has the score of the user. I'm assuming its on the user object:

```
def get_rank
    scores = User.select(:score).joins(:response, :answers).where(:answers => [:correct => true]).order('score DESC').group(:score).all
    # example result: [24, 22, 21, 20 ...]
    rank = scores.index(score) + 1
end
```

The result of that statement gives you a sorted array of all actually applied scores. Since you do know the current user's score, you can get the index of that score, which is also the rank number.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me. I just had to add a map before index in order to get it working in my case. So `rank = scores.map(&:score).index(self.score) + 1`